# User of stored process, which variable to use?

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

When i look in a SAS log, there are 4 different Variables to grab User:

```
 _METAPERSON
 _METAUSER
 _SECUREUSERNAME
 _USERNAME
```

When i check the log, all 4 variables have the same value when i execute the process. So i builded a process which checked _Metauser for some specific user, so that only the users i wanted could do something. 
But a colleague of me had the problem that in the variable was not the username stored for him when he called the process, but username@Context. In the other 3 variables, there was only username stored for him, so maybe i can change to one of them. I can not use Metauser, because for some persons there could be an @Context after username.

No i have the problem, which variable to use? What is the difference between the 4 variables? Which to use, to be sure that i only (and always) get the pure username, no matter from where and which programm/Version the User is calling the process?

- At the moment i use Sas 9.3 and run the process via webservice
- I switched to SECUREUSERNAME for now, but i am not sure if this can make problems for other users, at the moment only 3 work with this process, but there will be a lot more soon
- Our authorization concept is based on metadata, so i think maybe i should use _Metaperson...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ***_SECUREUSERNAME*** macro variable is created when the application server executes a Stored Process. The value of _SECUREUSERNAME contains the client identity and this value will be written into the _USERNAME macro variable if _USERNAME doesn't already contain a value.
Under most circumstances, the value of _SECUREUSERNAME will be the same as _USERNAME

***_USERNAME*** Specifies the value for the user name obtained from Web client authentication.

***_METAPERSON*** Specifies the Person metadata name that is associated with the _METAUSER login variable. The value of this variable can be UNKNOWN. This variable cannot be modified by the client.

**_METAUSER** Specifies the login username that is used to connect to the metadata server. This variable cannot be modified by the client.

There is no easy answer to your question, because it depends on your set up. Do your users have to login by using Metaserver? Is your code always accessed using the WebService? User IDs, what are they, are they ID from AD? Is Single-Sign-On (SSO) enabled? How are the IDs configured on SAS? Do people use Trusted Users to connect?

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: Standard Case is accessing SAS Stored Process Webservice via SSO. But there could also be an manual authentification on Webservice (after timeout or initially for some User) and in very rare Cases also running processes in EG. My colleague is using SSO like me, also he has exact same metadata user settings, so it is strange that the @Context is added for Metauser. He works in another department, so it must be something about the User-Settings there, but he can not say anything about this...

Comment: I will use _SECUREUSERNAME for now, because it seems to work, i accepted your answer already, but maybe you can add something about my last comment

Comment: Something to clarify (caught me out today) - _METAUSER is NOT the SAS metadata login username but in fact the OS login username..

Comment: @rawfocus it is OS when OS login is used at SAS logon screen. If you were to use a sas identity instead, it would pick up SAS usaername.

Answer (score 1):

I am using _METAUSER. Now, our systems are set up with SSO, so the username is always without the "@". I have used it without SSO as well, but then I had to use %scan(&_METAUSER,1,@) to strip away the @context part.

Comment: Hm, my colleague uses SSO and gets the @ part anyway (only for metauser). The scan option would be a workaround, but i would prefer to work without some extra-functions.

Answer (score 1):

From testing in a Stored Process session, 9.2 (windows) environment with SSO:

**OS username (in my case, my windows ID)**

- _METAUSER  (when signing in with OS login, eg with SSO, see @Vasilij Nevlev comment in accepted answer)
- _SECUREUSERNAME

**SAS username (in metadata)**

- _METAPERSON - *Specifies the person metadata name
  that is associated with the
  _METAUSER login variable.*  Not sure how this can be unknown, as SMC won't let you enter a blank value.. (anonymous web user is webanon)
- _USERNAME - definitely the username as you can use this along with _password in the URL to bypass the SAS login screen.

Comment: Good to know about the login via URL. +1. By the way, you will get different results if the stored process is run on workspace server. It fought me out when I forced execution to workspace server. Secure username become "(process)" for all users.